# Homebrew cask Calling `brew cask` with the `--caskroom` flag is disabled

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

When I type `$ brew cask` in iterm2. I have tired only use `brew` can work, but use cask then return this error.

then

```
Error: Calling `brew cask` with the `--caskroom` flag is disabled!
There is no replacement.
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cli/options.rb:53:in `block (3 levels) in process_arguments'
```

I use MacBook Pro 13.

homebrew config

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 1.3.6
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 270b752f5d9d218bfbed6fe85b6974fa653fb25f
Last commit: 2 weeks ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: 97f00b13e1bc310cfdf7b419a1844632781b88b9
Core tap last commit: 28 minutes ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /usr/local/Homebrew
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
HOMEBREW_BOTTLE_DOMAIN: https://homebrew.bintray.com
CPU: quad-core 64-bit haswell
Homebrew Ruby: 2.3.3 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
Clang: 9.0 build 900
Git: 2.13.5 => /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/bin/python
Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
Java: 1.8.0_111
macOS: 10.13-x86_64
Xcode: 9.0.1
CLT: N/A
X11: N/A
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you set `HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS` environment variable?
If so, all you need is to remove the `--caskroom` flag from it.